# Why are $v=(1,-2,2)$ and $w=(-1,0,3)$ not parallel? When are two vectors parallel?

Tags: vectors

Why are $v=(1,-2,2)$ and $w=(-1,0,3)$ not parallel? When are two vectors parallel? Please help me. I can't understand this.

Comment: Two vectors, as you denote them, are parallel if and only if one of them is a scalar multiple of the other one...and to be sure, and since many times the zero vector is excluded from this definition, we could also add that the scalar must be non-zero

Comment: Why not start with the two-dimensional case where it's easier to **draw pictures**? Then you should easily be able to convince yourself that (for example) $(1,-2)$ and $(-1,0)$ are not parallel, while $(1,-2)$ and $(3,-6)$ are, and from that you can figure out the general rule.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

> When are two vectors parallel?

If you have the coordinates, it's very easy to check: two vectors are **parallel** if they are (non-zero) scalar multiples of each other.

> Why are $v=(1,-2,2)$ and $w=(-1,0,3)$ not parallel?

Following above; because there is no scalar $k$ such that $(1,-2,2)=k\cdot (-1,0,3)$.

---

Addition after the comment.

The vectors $(-6,0,4)$ and $(3,0,-2)$ are parallel because $(-6,0,4)= \color{blue}{-2} \cdot (3,0,-2)$.

Comment: Can you give me an example of parallel vectors please?

Comment: @sam I edited my answer to include an example.

Answer (score 0):

if they are parallel, then we have a real number $\alpha$ for which we have
$$(1;-2;2)=\alpha(-1;0;3)$$ so we get
$$1=\alpha$$
$$-2=0$$
$$2=3\alpha$$
which can not be

Answer (score 0):

They are not parallel because they are not multiple one of the other (i.e. they are linearly independent) that is we can't find any $k \in \mathbb{R}$  such that

$$\vec v=k \vec w$$

As an example $\vec v=(1,-2,2)$ and $\vec u=(-2,4,-4)$ are parallel with $k=-2$.